# What's wrong with this tsql?

Tags: t-sql, transactions, batch-file

When executing the following script, I get the error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Invalid column name 'b'.

Anyone can explain it please? Thanks.

```
DROP TABLE ttt;
CREATE TABLE ttt(a nvarchar)

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                FROM    sys.columns
                WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ttt')
                        AND name = 'b' )
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   sys.columns
                 WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ttt')
                        AND name = 'a' ) 
    BEGIN

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].ttt ADD b NVARCHAR

        UPDATE  [dbo].ttt
        SET     b = a

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].ttt DROP COLUMN a
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's trying to compile all of these statements before it executes the 1st:

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].ttt ADD b NVARCHAR

    UPDATE  [dbo].ttt
    SET     b = a

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].ttt DROP COLUMN a
```

(In fact, it tries to compile the *entire batch*, not just these statements, but the point still stands - at the point it's trying to compile the `UPDATE`, the column does not exist)

When it's trying to compile the `UPDATE` statement, it consults the table metadata and correctly finds that the column doesn't exist.

Try `EXEC`ing the update statement.

```
    EXEC('UPDATE  [dbo].ttt
    SET     b = a');
```

And also, what Oded says about you probably wanting to specify a size for the column (otherwise, it defaults to the most pointless datatype ever - an `nvarchar(1)`)

---

This script definitely runs without errors:

```
CREATE TABLE ttt(a nvarchar)

IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
                FROM    sys.columns
                WHERE   object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ttt')
                        AND name = 'b' )
    AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
                 FROM   sys.columns
                 WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.ttt')
                        AND name = 'a' ) 
    BEGIN

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].ttt ADD b NVARCHAR

        EXEC('UPDATE  [dbo].ttt
        SET     b = a');

        ALTER TABLE [dbo].ttt DROP COLUMN a
    END
```

Comment: @Yousui - I just copied your entire script onto a clean server, removed the `drop table ttt` at the top, changed the `UPDATE` statement as specified above, and ran it without error. Is it exactly the same error still? Are there later parts of the batch (that you haven't shown us) that also reference column b, that will be being compiled before the change occurs?

Comment: Sorry i missed one point. i select just the if  statement with its body, without  the create table statement.

Comment: yes i try to execute the create and if statements at the same time, it  works. If i just execute the if statement, i still get the error. I don't know why, can you explain it please? Thank.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the code in a stored procedure it should work. Just make sure the table exists with both columns a and column b when you create the procedure. Then after the procedure has been created you can drop the table and test it.